# Output voltage for pmos with Vt= -0.8

Tags: pmos

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE5Xmx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What is V<sub>X</sub>?

I am having confusion between 2.8 V or 3 V.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It will be hard to address your confusion without knowing what makes you think that it's 2.8V. What is your reasoning?

Comment: pmos to turn ON, Vsg > |Vt|. substituting the values made me think so. Vs - 2 > 0.8

Comment: Wait, this is DC? So, if the mosfet is on and conducts, what do you think the voltage 
 will be across the capacitor at steady state?

Comment: Actually you already created the circuit in circuitlab, so why dont you click that sweet "simulate this circuit" button and see for yourself?

Comment: I tried to simulate it and I am getting 3V at the output but when I changed the Pmos with Nmos then the output is showing N/A. So, I wanted to know why Vsg > |Vt| can't be applicable here. As I have already mentioned that I have confusion between 2.8V and 3V. The simulation result is showing 3V and theoretical value I am getting is 2.8V.

Comment: @Ravi: **"So, I wanted to know why Vsg > |Vt| can't be applicable here."** Sure it can. |Vt| = 0.8 V, Vsg = 3V - 2V = 1V. Which means: Vsg > |Vt| -> 1V > 0.8V. So, is the FET on or not?

Comment: Ok, now I understood. FET is ON and it will pass the 3V. I was interchanging the source and drain terminals which caused the problem. Thank you for explaining me